# Is there a way to remove 'iat' option from jwt payload in jsonwebtoken library typescript?

Tags: typescript, react-redux, jwt

I want to remove 'iat' option from header for the creation of correct request to the external server. I've tried to do something like this

```
let token = jwt.sign(
    {payload: payload, iat: undefined},
    generateAndGetDeviceKey(),
    { algorithm: 'HS512' }
);
```

but it doesn't work. I got error

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: "iat" should be a number of seconds

Comment: Why do you need to remove that number?

Answer (score 3):

You can pass the `noTimestamp` option, which will prevent adding `iat`.

Something like this should work.

```
let token = jwt.sign(
    {payload: payload},
    generateAndGetDeviceKey(),
    { algorithm: 'HS512', noTimestamp: true }
);
```

Comment: that's basically right, but OP should be aware that `noTimestamp` literally means what it says, so the token will also have no `exp` and `nbf` timestamps.

Comment: I assume that `exp` can be added manually to the payload then, if for some reason the token should have `exp` but no `iat`.

Comment: *I assume* - give it a try!

Comment: I'll leave it as an exercise for the OP ;)